# What happens when the computer restarts to a Google Gears worker?

Tags: google-gears

Regarding the worker pool, what happens when the computer restarts? Does the worker continue where it left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Actually workers terminate immediately upon navigating away from the page. This must protect from run away processes taking over the computer.

As a result, as soon as the browser closes on a computer restart, the worker will terminate.

And it will not continue where it left off.

Tip: One must program atomically as to expect if computation can stop at any moment in time.